# Empty Steam window on OS X

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Registered on steampowered.com.
Downloaded the steam app, when starting it, just an empty app shows up : 
[image]

When trying to run the `/Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/steam_osx` manually here's the output :

```
[2016-12-26 14:55:08] Verifying installation...
[2016-12-26 14:55:08] Verification complete  
CHIDDeviceListSDL(): Couldn't load libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib, not enumerating devices
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomeintro.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomeintro.res', no such file
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccount.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccount.res', no such file
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountaccountname.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountaccountname.res', no such file
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountemail.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountemail.res', no such file
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountnamecollision.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountnamecollision.res', no such file
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatingaccount.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatingaccount.res', no such file
[2016-12-26 14:55:09] Background update loop checking for update. . .
[2016-12-26 14:55:09] Checking for available updates...
Errors in public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountprintdetails.res:
error loading file 'public/subpanelwelcomecreatenewaccountprintdetails.res', no such file
```

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Not posting as an answer, because I don't have a Mac to test such a thing - however, I found this issue (here, on the Steam forums)[https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/2/350542145699765724/], with a possible solution.  You will need to type some commands into the Terminal in order to resolve the issue.  (Or just perform the changes manually)

Answer (score 2):

This one worked http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/2/282992646978253149/
Basically all Steam files from
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/Steam.AppBundle/Steam/Contents/MacOS` must be renamed to lowercase.
Execute that :

> ls | while read line ; do file=$(echo $line | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); mv $line $file; done

in all of these folders : `public`, `steam/cached`, `friends`, `graphics`, `servers` (relative to the folder specified above.)